# Error java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wordcount_classes.WordCount$Map while running the map reduce program

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and trying to run the Map reduce program that is Word Count and i am getting the following error                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wordcount_classes.WordCount$Map and                                                                                                WordCount.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private Text word = new Text();

   public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       String line = value.toString();
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
           word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
           context.write(word, one);
       }
   }
} 

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

   public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
     throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       int sum = 0;
       for (IntWritable val : values) {
           sum += val.get();
       }
       context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Configuration conf = new Configuration();

      Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

   job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
   job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

   job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
   job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

   job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
   job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

   FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
   job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);    
   job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

wordcount_classes directory contents are

```
-rw-r--r--   1 sagar supergroup       1855 2014-10-03 13:15 /user/sagar  /wordcount_classes/WordCount$Map.class
-rw-r--r--   1 sagar supergroup       1627 2014-10-03 13:15 /user/sagar/wordcount_classes/WordCount$Reduce.class
-rw-r--r--   1 sagar supergroup       1453 2014-10-03 13:14 /user/sagar/wordcount_classes/WordCount.class
-rw-r--r--   1 sagar supergroup       3109 2014-10-03 13:15 /user/sagar/wordcount_classes/wordcount.jar
```

}

and i am compiling the program by following command

```
hadoop jar wordcount_classes/wordcount.jar wordcount_classes/WordCount input r1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following :

1. Did you compile as runnable jar
2. Did you run from the folder the jar contains
   or
3. Run using the following command

   ```
    hadoop jar <path_to_jar>/wordcount.jar WordCount <hdfs_path_to_input>/input <hdfpath>/r1
   ```

Comment: Where are these input and output directory should be that is in hdfs files or elsewhere ?

Comment: input should be the input source file located in hdfs and output is a directory in hdfs but it should not be created , output will be created by the program itself. Let me know if your issue is fixed

Comment: How do i know  file system path of directory created in hdfs ?

Comment: where the WordCount .class file should be ? should it be in hdfs file system only ?

Comment: neednot be in hdfs, it can be in the local system

Comment: everytime is it necessary to have new output directory ? that is every time we have to specify new directory and again same error is prompted

Comment: The output directory shouldn't exist, it will be created by the program.If already exists it will show an error saying output directory already exits.

Comment: Along with these error two warnings are also prompter those are                                                                     14/10/03 17:35:46 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/10/03 17:35:46 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String). i am not getting where the problem is ? could please tell me?

Comment: for time being ignore WARN, focus only on ERROR

Comment: i have added one more sentence to the program and which is job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class) and that gives error                                                                retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)

Comment: Thanks @K S Nidhin for your help . the program ran . The problem was i did not keep the program in package . but i had to keep the program in hdfs in order to run the program .

Comment: Happy that it helped, upvote the comment that helped you the most and accept the answer.Thanks

Comment: @ K S Nidhin is it necessary, any map reduce program to be in any package ?

Comment: no need.The wordcount program is a part of the hadoop examples collection package.The mapreduce code can be just like a simple java class